# using setTimeout in javascript to do simple animation

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I am using setTimeout to create animation in Javascript, but it does not seem to work. Only the 1st move of the animation is executed, no subsequent moves.

I tried on two different laptops using Firefox, one doesn't throw any error, but the one says `self.animateCallback is not a function`. I also see other errors like saying my timeout function is useless or "compile-and-go" when I tried diff ways. Doesn't seem to get it working. I tried `"function(self){self.animateCallback()}"` and `"self.animateCallback"` (with and without quotes).

The code is below, it is part of a prototype method.

```
    increment : function(incr, target, tick) {
    var self = this;

    self.animateCallback = function()
    {
        var done = Math.abs(self.currValue - target) < Math.abs(incr);
        if(!self.animateCallback || done) {

            if(done) {
                self.updateAngle(self.currValue/self.maxValue);
                self.stopAnimation(); //just setting animateCallback to null
            }
        }
        else
        {
            self.updateAngle((self.currValue+incr)/self.maxValue);
            setTimeout(self.animateCallback, tick);
        }

    }
    self.animateCallback.call();
},
```

Comment: We would need to see more of the code to know what's wrong.  Obviously something is messing with either this, self or self.animateCallback as the code should not have the issue you report if one of these wasn't being messed with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got a feeling the problem has something to do with the line `setTimeout(self.animateCallback...`, which is accessing the function through a closure and a property. It should be neater, at least, to do it like this:

```
increment : function(incr, target, tick) {
    var self = this;

    var animateCallback = function()
    {
        var done = Math.abs(self.currValue - target) < Math.abs(incr);
        if(done) {
            self.updateAngle(self.currValue/self.maxValue);
            self.animateTimeout = null;
        }
        else
        {
            self.updateAngle((self.currValue+incr)/self.maxValue);
            self.animateTimeout = setTimeout(animateCallback, tick);
        }

    }
    animateCallback();
},
stopAnimation: function() {
    if (this.animateTimeout) {
        clearTimeout(this.animateTimeout);
        this.animateTimeout = null;
    }
},
```

Comment: I am refering to tt line also. In ur suggestion, it seems like stopAnimation is not neccessary. What i did instead in the end was to do sth like self.timer = setTimeout(function(obj){obj.animateCallback.call()};), tick, self);

Answer (score 0):

I think the error is that some other code is changing the value of `self.animateCallback` to something else. The first time through, `setTimeout` has the correct value for `self.animateCallback`, but after the first time, the value of `self.animateCallback` has changed to something else, which isn't a function, but is still a non-falsy value so that `!self.animateCallback` returns false.

You can try changing the if statement to this:

```
if((typeof self.animateCallback !== "function") || done) {

    if(done) {
        self.updateAngle(self.currValue/self.maxValue);
        self.stopAnimation(); //just setting animateCallback to null
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

try to pass an anonymous function to `setTimeout`, like

```
setTimeout(function(){ self.animateCallback(); }, tick);
```

hope it'll help.

Comment: This is not required and won't make a difference as `self.animateCallback()` is a function already.  One doesn't need an anonymous function with `setTimeout()`.